# Salesforce updating String field value with null when forced with an empty String

Tags: apex, string, null, text, empty

I noticed when you force an existing text field value with an empty String, instead of it's becoming an empty string it's becoming a null value.

For example, try below in Execute Anonymous.

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
Contact c = new Contact(lastname = 'test', firstname='ttt');
insert c;
c.firstname = '';
update c;
System.debug('Forced empty string value saved as: ' + [select firstname from Contact where Id = :c.Id].firstname);
Database.rollback(sp);
```

Is this the normal behaviour?

Also noticed it does not clear email if you assign '', and did not get any errors either.

E.g.

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
Contact c = new Contact(lastname = 'test', firstname='ttt', Email = 'test@test.com');
insert c;
c.firstname = '';
c.Email = '';
update c;
c = [select firstname, Email from Contact where Id = :c.Id];
System.debug('Forced empty string value saved as: ' + c.firstname +' and email: '+c.email);
Database.rollback(sp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run the above code, the debug output I receive is:

```
08:09:30.96 (4920148972)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|Forced empty string value saved as: null and email: null
```

I.e. both values get applied but both become null. For you, I wonder if there is some automation that prevents the Email being cleared?

To check this further, if I create a test object, Test__c, using the default settings during creation of the object type and with two custom fields, FirstName__c a string of 255 and default settings plus EMail an email with default settings, and I try this code:

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
Test__c c = new Test__c(Name = 'test', FirstName__c='ttt', Email__c = 'test@test.com');
insert c;
c.FirstName__c = '';
c.Email__c = '';
update c;
c = [SELECT FirstName__c, Email__c FROM Test__c WHERE Id = :c.Id];
System.debug('Forced empty string value saved as: ' + c.FirstName__c +' and email: '+c.Email__c);
Database.rollback(sp);
```

I get the following debug output:

```
08:18:43.109 (293581789)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|Forced empty string value saved as: null and email: null
```

Interestingly, updating the change of the FirstName__c field to use a string of whitespace, I find the insert appears to equally collapse to a null value when looking at the debug.

I then shifted the code into a unit test, like:

```
@IsTest
private class Test_Test {
    @IsTest
    static void testBehavior() {
        Test__c c = new Test__c(Name = 'test', FirstName__c='ttt', Email__c = 'test@test.com');
        insert c;
        c.FirstName__c = ' ';
        c.Email__c = '';
        update c;
        c = [SELECT FirstName__c, Email__c FROM Test__c WHERE Id = :c.Id];
        System.debug('Forced empty string value saved as: ' + c.FirstName__c +' and email: '+c.Email__c);
    }
}
```

In this context the debug still shows:

```
08:40:25.7 (150466565)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|Forced empty string value saved as: null and email: null
```

I then changed the `update c;` statement to be `Database.update(c);` which also results in nulls.

I could not find this behaviour explicitly documented anywhere so this is a really interesting observation. It seems that Apex, at least, treats any value that returns true from `String.isBlank` as null when updating fields via DML.

I ran these tests against Spring '21.

Comment: @Phik W Thanks, Yes. RE Email: My bad there seems to be an automation in the org which is prevents clearing email.

Answer (score 0):

This is so weird. I'm seeing the same behaviour for insert alone, using a custom object Text__c with a single Text[80] field called Text. In the following simple test method, the assert fails, demonstrating the issue.

```
@isTest static void TestHandlingOfEmptyStringDuringInsert(){
    Test__c test = new Test__c(Text__c='');
    insert(test);
    test=[SELECT Text__c FROM Test__c WHERE Id = :test.Id];
    System.assert(test.Text__c!=null, 'Text has been converted to null!');
}
```

Id love to at least see some kind of Salesforce knowledge article in this area - it seems very counterintuitive to me!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/165292)